# How to extract regions from a vector?

Tags: image, matlab, vector, matrix

I have a very long vector which represents different region areas. I want to identify and separate these regions from this vector. For example a small sample of the vector in question is given below:

```
 529         534         536         540         543         545         546

  Columns 99 through 105

         547         548         550         554         557         558         560

  Columns 106 through 112

         561         562         564         568         570         572         573

  Columns 113 through 119

         575         576         579         581         582         585         587

  Columns 120 through 126

         590         596         597         599         600         601         602

  Columns 127 through 133

         607         609         613         616         618         622         623

  Columns 134 through 140

         628         637         641         642         643         646         652

  Columns 141 through 147

         655         658         659        1031        1032        1034        1035

  Columns 148 through 154

        1044        1045        1046        1049        1051        1053        1060

  Columns 155 through 161

        1061        1068        1071        1072        1074        1077        1081

  Columns 162 through 168

        1084        1088        1110        1122        1143        1156        1175

  Columns 169 through 175

        1182        1191        1193        1195        1197        1200        1201

  Columns 176 through 182

        1205        1210        1214        1228        1239        1259        1267

  Columns 183 through 189

        1276        1286        1292        1297        1300        1307        1314

  Columns 190 through 196

        1318        1319        1321        1325        1337        1353        1362

  Columns 197 through 203

        1372        1381        1405        1411        1427        1432        1438

  Columns 204 through 210

        1443        1444        1801        1803        1805        1810        1811

  Columns 211 through 217

        1812        1815        1818        1822        1824        1825        1826

  Columns 218 through 224

        1829        1833        1835        1846        1852        1856        1860
```

The above vector is the result of `find` so all the zero's or non interest pixels are removed. The above vector represents a graph like this:

[image]

So my thinking is that the vector indexes experiencing large jumps will represent the region end and start. But I cant seem to put it in programming. My attempt so far is to go over the above vecotr using a loop and use a difference condition to find out the regions like so

```
for k = 1:length(ind)-1
    if((ind(k+1) - ind(k)) > 100)
       reg_2 = ind(k+1)
```

I set the threshold at 100 and if the difference between the two indexes is greater than 100 then the `k+1` is the start of the next region. But how do I measure the start of the first region? And wont my `reg_2` be overwritten every time this condition is true? How to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `diff` function with `findpeaks`. Since I don't have your data, I am just giving a prototype, but it should work.

```
th=200 %estiamted from the figure posted in the question. Used later.
diffVec=diff(vec);
[peaks,locs]=findpeaks(diffVec,'minpeakheight', th); %user-set threshold.
```

I think once you have the locations with the peak values, then it is trivial to select the region.

Edit 1: I tried with the data you posted. With a threshold of 200, I get 2 peaks, one at index 52 and other at 114. If I observe the data, it is in agreement:

```
vec(52)=659 & vec(53)=1031
vec(114)=1444 & vec(115)=1801
```

So the regions are: 1 to 52, 53 to 114 and 115 to end (i.e. 133).

Edit 2: Above regions are in terms of indices of vector and not values of vector. Values in those indices can easily be extracted as:

```
locs=[[1;locs] [locs;length(a)]];
locs(:,1)=locs(:,1)+1;
regions=[[0;a(locs(2:end,1))] [a(locs(1:end-1,2));max(a)]];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Parag, but this does not seem to work. I tried it on a different vector: http://pastebin.com/UiSkJ7Da and it gave me these peaks ``253   582   400``. But judging by just looking at the vector I gave, region 1 is ``0 to 122`` then ``375 to 563``, ``1145 to 1292`` and ``1697 to 2242``. This does not look like what ``findpeaks`` gave me. So how will I be able to successfully extract the regions? Thank you

Comment: @FarazKhan Oh. I misunderstood your problem. I thought regions are given in terms of vector indices. No problem though. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Parag. But your edit2 code gives me this error: ``CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
``

Comment: tyr `vec=vec'` before calculating `regions`.

Comment: Thanks lot for your help @Parag, but it is producing strange region selections. For example in this data set: http://pastebin.com/K8HisUHs, the correct regions are ``0-122``, ``375-563``, ``1145-1297`` and ``1697-2254`` but it is producing: ``[0,375;122,1145;563,1697;1297,2254]``. Its basically connecting the start of one region to the start of the next, and then the end of that region to the start of the further next. :(

Comment: @FarazKhan See my edit. I feel like I am not keeping the code generic enough. Still, I hope this serves your purpose.